# Geocoding and ReverseGeocoding in iOS using Google Maps

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

I want to add **Google Maps** in a UIView that I added in MainStoryboard (Because I want to control maps place and size).

The map shows correctly but does not listen to the events. I have added `<GMSMapViewDelegate>` protocol in `ViewController.h` and also the methods in `ViewController.m` and when i set the `UIViewController` view as the map view (Googles example `self.view = GMSMapView`) everything works fine.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set your `ViewController` as a `GMSMapView` **delegate**.

in `viewDidLoad`:

```
mapView.delegate = self;
```